# Convert pdf to doc and save in folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

These two functions work alone. I wanted to write them down now, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Does anyone have a hint?

I want the "pdfToDoc" function to work with my array list (var Files [])

---

```
var files = [];

function getListOfId(){

  var folderId = "11tjb_odTJ2E_eXXXXXXXDViQQJ8u9-g";
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

  while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getId());
  //console.log(files);
}
```

---

```
function pdfToDoc() {
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById('16wkcb8XXXXXXXXmpQ19_yM-K2QxxIc').getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true,
    convert: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  //Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);
}
```

---

### I tried the following, unfortunately it didn't work. I am happy about every hint.

```
function pdfToDoc() {
  
  var files = [];

  function getListOfId(){
  var folderId = "11tjb_odTJ2E_XXXXXXX9DViQQJ8u9-g";
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

  while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getId());
}
  
  for(var i=0;i<files.lenght;i++){
    
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(files[i][0]).getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true,
    convert: true
  };

  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);
  var docFileId = docFile.getId();  
  var saveDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docFileId);
    
  DriveApp.getFolderById("1-k_0SXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAyX").addFile(saveDocFile);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(saveDocFile);
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating your code and it seems that the problem lies with your function **getListOfId()** which wasn't called anywhere in the code. To fix this, you should add a function call before you loop into the file ids.

This is how I made it work on my end and the code looks like this(May not be exactly how you want it; I also fixed the typo? **lenght** to **length**):

```
function pdfToDoc() {
  
  var files = [];

  function getListOfId(){
    var folderId = "1BpPZynsF5tjI5bysoOeHjKbr3gFCm7P8";
    var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
    while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getId());
}
  getListOfId()
  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(files[i]).getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: fileBlob.getName(),
      mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
    };
    var options = {
      ocr: true,
      convert: true
    };
  
    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);
    var docFileId = docFile.getId();  
    var saveDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docFileId);
      
    DriveApp.getFolderById("1BpPZynsF5tjI5bysoOeHjKbr3gFCm7P8").addFile(saveDocFile);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(saveDocFile);
    }
}
```

You can change the code on your own preference on how you will be calling the **getListOfId()** function.

Answer (score 0):

What I see that you're putting function inside a function instead you should call the function in that function.

Try this:

```
function pdfToDoc() {
  
 var files = []; 

  getListOfId(files);   
  for(var i=0;i<files.lenght;i++){
    
    var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(files[i][0]).getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: fileBlob.getName(),
      mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
    };
    var options = {
      ocr: true,
      convert: true
    };

    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);
    var docFileId = docFile.getId();  
    var saveDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docFileId);
    
    DriveApp.getFolderById("1-k_0SXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAyX").addFile(saveDocFile);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(saveDocFile);
  }}

  function getListOfId(files){
    var folderId = "11tjb_odTJ2E_XXXXXXX9DViQQJ8u9-g";
    var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

    while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getId());
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately your approach does not work. I don't get any error messages or anything like that. : /

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `pdfToDoc` function should use a parameter / argument for the file id instead of a hardcoded id
2. Somehow you should send one by one the collected file ids to `pdfToDoc`

Here is one simple way to implement the above

```
var files = [];

function getListOfId(){

  var folderId = "11tjb_odTJ2E_eXXXXXXXDViQQJ8u9-g";
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

  while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getId());
  //console.log(files);

}

function pdfToDoc(id) { // modified
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob(); // modified
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true,
    convert: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  //Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);
}

/**
 * Added
 */
function main(){
   getListOfId();
   // files is a global variable
   files.forEach(function(id){
     pdfToDoc(id);
   });
}
```

Additional note:

Using global variables might be tricky. I suggest you to move your `files` variable initialization to the "main" function, even better, make that your `getListOfId` function returns the collected ids instead of modifying a global variable. Tip: Learn the basics of functional programming.